# How to add image according to a condition on SQL table

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

I'm working on a personal project

I have a windows form c# where I add people with a field where I choose the gender and name of the person.

When I click on the button, it adds a person to the table `person` of `human` database.

Then on another form I want to display the panel of all the people present in the database.

Display of the persons will be represented by a picture of male/female symbol

I have a `person` table, with `name` and `gender` attributes. And I would like that each time I add a person, automatically according to the `gender` of the person, a picture of symbol of a woman or a man is added to the table.

The final goal, like I said it before, is to display in a separate picturebox (Windows form C#) each of the `persons` in the table with their appropriate image(according to `gender`).

And I'll add a hover option on each picturebox thats shows name of the person when you use your mouse (I dont need help here, just to let you know how it will works).

I don't know either, if it's the right way to approach this problem or if the solution is more on the c# side with a condition on the image display (it seems much more complex to me).

Do I need to create another SQL table named `picture` and I link it with `person` but here again, I don't know how i can  implement the image condition between `picture` and `person` table  and make it works with C# form

SQL script:

```sql
CREATE TABLE persons(
  id INT(100) auto increment, PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(1000),
  gender VARCHAR(7)
);
```

Here arepictures of how it will looks...

**Add form**
[image: add form]

**Panel**
[image: panel]

I hope I made myself clear, thanks!

Comment: That symbol should not be in the database (for each record at least). In your case it's most likely better to have the image resource part of your GUI and display the proper one depending on the data value (being `Enum`, `int` or `bool`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the images are static i.e. *They don't change when the user change and all males have the same picture and all the females have the same picture*

I think it is not a good idea to put the image in the database. From the C# side you can check if the user is a male or a female and load it from some resources folder in your C# project.

Let me know if I got something wrong with your thoughts.